# Fast Update For a Table

Tags: sql-update, updates, updating

I need to update CustomerValue table for 4000 customers for 20 different options.

It exactly comes out to 80,000 records.

I wrote this:

```
Update CustomerValue Set Value = 100 where Option in    
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
```

But it is taking time. I was wondering If I can use PL/SQL block or any other way to make it run faster. Few minutes are okay....It ran for 11 minutes so I cancelled it.

Note: There is no ROWID in that table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If your condition is regular like this
>   (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
>
> 1100000 rows 6 second.

```
UPDATE CustomerValue
SET DEGER = 100
WHERE Value >= 1 AND Value <=20
```